# How does .rodata occupy ROM space?

Tags: c++, c, esp32

I'm using esp32c3(a riscv architecture chip). I use a global string array initialized with string, and it occupies ram and rom. When I add "const" keyword before the array, the array is put into .rodata by link script. Then I found that the ram consumption reduces(this is in line with my expectation). However, the compiled .bin firmware file size is reduced.
I think even if the const keyword is added to the array, the size of the compiled .bin firmware file should remain unchanged, because the strings are always need to be stored in the firmware.This puzzles me.

Other info:
If a pointer is used to point to the same string content(instead of using string array, and the pointer is is located at .sdata), the .bin file size will increase, ram consumption not increase.

At the same time, I saw this paragraph in the official data of the chip, but I didn't fully understand the meaning:

*By default, constant data is placed by the linker into a region mapped to the MMU flash cache. This is the same as the IROM (code executed from flash) section, but is for read-only data not executable code.*
*The only constant data not placed into this memory type by default are literal constants which are embedded by the compiler into application code. These are placed as the surrounding function’s executable instructions.*

Comment: "The ram consumption of the program reduces the size of the array (this is in line with my expectation), but the executable app file does not increase the size of the const array": I do not understand either of these statements. Why should the array size increase?

Comment: You tagged your question with `linux`, `stm32` and `esp32`. Which platform are you actually asking about?

Comment: Also, "ROM" means something very specific - a specific kind of non-volatile storage. It's not a generic for "read-only memory". The way you're using it is extremely confusing.

Comment: The embedded platform I use is esp32c3, a riscv architecture chip.

ROM means the read-only memory，in other words, I mean the size of bin file. Sorry for didn't explain it clearly.

I think that when there is a global string array, whether it is added with const or not, these data should be stored in the read-only memory area. So the size of the .bin file will increase by the same size.

But on my embedded platform , when adding the const keyword, the file size reduces the size of this array. So I don't know where these strings are stored. This is what puzzles me.

Comment: ROM does not mean read only file. It means a specific type of memory hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify it in your question, but I'm assuming your array is initialized with some non-zero data.

Your typical executable will look something like this [[source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format):

[image: ELF file]

When you add the `const` keyword, the array simply gets moved from the `.data` section into the `.rodata`. The net change in file size is 0.

If you also add `static` keyword to your array, it will be moved into the `.text` section, but again, the size will remain the same.

See Wikipedia page on [Data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) for the information about each section.

Comment: This is an array of strings, like this:
char myArray[] = "abc";

Just like you said, when adding the const keyword(or also add static), the net change in file size is 0.
I thought it should be the same as you said, because this string array should occupy read-only memory.
But on my embedded platform (esp32c3), when adding the const keyword, the file size reduces the size of this array.
This is what puzzles me.

Comment: @ZH.sd what does it mean for a “file size” to reduce “the size of an array”?

Comment: "file" refers to the bin file compiled by the code or other types of executable files.
When I add a global string, for example, 10 KB of string content is stored in myArray [], the compiled file will also increase by 10 KB. But when I add the const keyword to it, the file size is reduced by 10KB. I don't know where the 10KB string is stored - I understand that it should be placed in .rodata segment, which should take up ROM space. @Sneftel

Comment: So the array size isn’t “reduced”?

Comment: @Sneftel  Yes, of course, the size of the array will not be reduced. Sorry, my english expression is not very good.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correct, you expect the following to happen when you add `const` to your array:

1. the RAM consumption is reduced
2. the ROM consumption is increased.

But you can only observe 1), not 2).

Without looking at the exact sections that are used, you are missing one thing:

If you have an array like this:

```c
char myArray[] = "This is the String for my Array!";
```

Then you need 2 chunks of memory:

1. RAM area for holding your array
2. ROM area for holding the string literal you are using to initialized that array.

At startup the initialization string is copied from ROM to RAM area.

If you make the array `const`, there is no more need to copy the string into RAM and you will see RAM consumption drop.
But wrt ROM consumption, there is no big difference as the data is already there.

Therefore ROM area will not be reduced.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When add const, my understanding is:  
1. the RAM consumption is reduced.  
2. the ROM consumption is same as before.    

I understand what you mean. Whether you add const keyword or not, the strings value always consume ROM.    
But the reality is that when I add the const keyword, the ROM consumption is reduced, which I really don't understand.

Comment: You did not mention any numbers. Copying the ROM data into RAM might require an extra entry in some "copy-to-ram" list that is handled during startup. If you don't need to copy, you also don't need that entry. It's likely to consist of 2 pointers and a size value. That could be the reduction you saw. Depending on location in memory, this list might have an entry for your array or it might be part of a larger memory area. Without way more details, it's hard to tell.

Comment: For example，char myArray[] stores 10 KB of string data. The existence of this array will increase the ram consumption by 10KB and the rom consumption by 10KB too.  When the const keyword is added to this array, the ram consumption is reduced by 10KB (which is in line with my expectation), but the rom consumption is also reduced by 10KB.   ROM consumption refers to the size of the program binary. On the esp32c3 platform I currently use, all the code will be compiled to generate a bin file. I think the string data will occupy a certain space in it.

Comment: That would mean you get the same size as without the whole array? That is strange. Do you actually use that array at all? Maybe the linker just discards it completely.

Comment: Yes, with the const keyword, the size of the bin file is as large as without this array. I did use the array in the code (I printf it).      So it really makes me feel very confused.    I suspect that this data may be nested into some storage gaps. In short, the phrase in the official document is very key, but I can't fully understand its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason is that at the OS level memory gets allocated in fixed sized chunks for reasons owing to the hardware in use, if you add an object to .rodata that doesn't cross a boundary of that size then no more memory will need to be allocated than if that object were not part of the program. I can't tell you anything about the embedded platform you are using but for x86 for example that fixed size will be either 4kb, 2mb or 4mb (that is, the page size).